# Bind ObservableCollection as source for different CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` named `myCollection` that should be binded to two `CollectionViewSource`s (`AllItems` and `SelectedItems`).

`AllItems`'s source property is binded to the `myCollection`. `SelectedItems`'s source property should be bind to `myCollection` items which `IsSelected == true`.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //fields and interface implementations
    public string Name {//proper code};
    public bool? IsSelected {//proper code};
}

// some where else in the MainWindow
AllItems.Source = myCollection;
SelectedItems.Source = myCollection.Where(input=>input.IsSelected==true);
```

**Problem:** Every thing is OK when the Window is loaded. But when the `IsSelected` value for some items in the `myCollection` is changed obviously it has no effect on the `SelectedItems`. So to overcome this problem I update the source property of the `SelectedItems` every time an `IsSelected` property is changed.

**Question:** How can I do these kind of binding so that there is no need to manually update the source property of the `SelectedItems`?

Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should unconditionally remove your manual filtering setup and replace it with something more appropriate. The choice of what to replace with depends mainly on what .NET version you are targeting.

If targeting .NET 4.5 then a simple solution is and instead  enable [live filtering](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/05/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-10-live-shaping/) on the collection view.

For earlier versions of .NET you will have to do some manual work no matter what, but it is better to just call [`Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.refresh.aspx) on the collection view that re-bind your control. To do this, you should defer the filtering to the collection view itself by setting the [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx) event handler from XAML.

Answer (score 1):

After the changes in `MyClass` you should raise `PropertyChanged Event`.

If you already do this than you should look at your `SelectedItems.Source` in Debug mode. Maybe its the correct value already there but its not shown to you.

I mean if `SelectedItems.Source` belongs to some visible Elements - GUI - you should refresh it on the screen. Cause the other way the value is there but will not be shown till your Element on the Screen is repainted.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad - than you should try my suggestion with Debug mode

Comment: the answer is this: there is no way to make automatic update, I have to so some refreshing in the correct place.

Comment: yes it is the answer. And I have post it as answer - that you have to refresh